# Android Studio heap snapshot analyzer - what does "Dominating size" represent?

Tags: android, android-studio, hprof

After dumping heap in Android Studio and viewing the created snapshot, there's a field called "dominating size".
What does it stand for?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the size of that object + everything it keeps alive by direct or indirect references.

I'm not sure about Android Studio, but generally, "dominating" would mean that you only count the objects that are *only* accessible through your Bitmap objects here -- i.e., if your Bitmap is freed, all of those objects could be freed as well.

In your case, each Bitmap object itself only takes 60 bytes -- but they each have a (separately allocated) pixel buffer of some kind that they're keeping alive.

Comment: So it looks like dominating size and retained heap are synonyms

Comment: My comment is a little wrong: here is what the documentation says about dominating size and retained heap: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-hprof.html